# Remove sharp edges (creases?)

Tags: modeling

As shown in the image my model does have sharp edges and I don't really know why they are there. The hoodie hat a pocket before and I removed it. The purple lines stayed though. I read that the purple lines are creases. Therefore I tried to set the mean crease to 0 and the edge crease value to -1. This unfortunately did not have an effect on the sharp edges of the modell. Does anyone else have an idea?

PS: I would not net the crease line anymore if that helps to solve the problem.

[image: sharp edges on object]

Comment: You have it marked as a seam - perhaps the normals got inverted. Try selecting all in edit mode and then `mesh > normals > recalculate outside`

Comment: Hi Christopher thanks for the reply but this did not change anything for me.